# "magical" styling of HTML elements with jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

So I've discovered the [jQuery UI `.button()`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) function which can style `<button>` elements:

```
$("button").button();
```

This works very nicely. Is there something similar for `<input>`, `<div>`, or other elements?

Comment: According to the DOCs it already can.

Comment: It's the DOCUMENTATION :P  http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have discovered the [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/home) plugin which adds the [`.button`](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/) function. There are [many plugins available](http://plugins.jquery.com/) for jQuery. I can almost guarantee someone's written a plugin to do exactly what you want, but you haven't exactly described what it is that you want.

It's possible that `.button` will do what you want to `input:button`, `a`, and `div` elements.

Comment: I don't think .button() is a plugin. Or is it?

Comment: It very much is an addition to `jQuery` as [it's not included in the jQuery core API](http://api.jquery.com/). It may or may not be jQuery UI's `.button` function, but it most certainly *is* from a plugin.